# Kotlin: clicking button to go to new activity results in crash

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, onclick

I'm new to Kotlin and Android Studio and I tried to find a solution to this problem and cannot find it on my own.

There are two activities and I want to jump to the second activity when a button is clicked. The button's id is "startbutton". The class of the second activity is named "SecondScreen".

This is my code, I double checked it with several tutorials and still cannot find the error that results in the crash of the app, the crash occurs while running the app as soon as I click on the button:

```
package com.example.kotlintestgebiet

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_title_screen.*

class TitleScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen)
        title = "KotlinApp"

        //At this point I also tried 
        // val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.startbutton) 
        // and then button.setOnClickListener 
        // but it didn't work either. 

        startbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@TitleScreen, SecondScreen::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the Second activity:

```
package com.example.kotlintestgebiet

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.view.View

var mMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

class SecondScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen)

    }

    // 1. Plays the sound
    fun playSound(view: View) {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.julie1)
            mMediaPlayer!!.isLooping = true
            mMediaPlayer!!.start()
        } else mMediaPlayer!!.start()
    }

    // 2. Pause playback
    fun pauseSound(view: View) {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mMediaPlayer!!.pause()
    }

    // 3. {optional} Stops playback
    fun stopSound(view: View) {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer!!.stop()
            mMediaPlayer!!.release()
            mMediaPlayer = null
        }
    }

    // 4. Closes the MediaPlayer when the app is closed
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer!!.release()
            mMediaPlayer = null
        }
    }
}
```

If there isn't a mistake in this piece of code: what mistakes is a beginner likely to make that results in the crash? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have a nice day!

LOGCAT error message when clicking the button in the app:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kotlintestgebiet, PID: 7666
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.kotlintestgebiet/com.example.kotlintestgebiet.SecondScreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1720)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5258)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5203)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5587)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5555)
        at com.example.kotlintestgebiet.TitleScreen$onCreate$1.onClick(TitleScreen.kt:22)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7862)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:15004)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7831)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:879)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29359)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: can you share the code of your second activity ?

Comment: I edited my original post and added the code of the second activity. thank you for your reply!

Comment: have you declared the second activity in the manifest File ?

Comment: I see no problem with both activities can you please add the error from the logcat ?

Comment: I added the logcat file. Sorry I haven't heard of the manifest file before. Could this be the problem?

Comment: as I said you must declare the Activity on the manifest

Comment: if you read the logcat it's said `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: add this in your manifest inside <application> tag `<activity android:name=".SecondScreen "> </activity>`

Comment: Thank you kindly Sir, this solved my problem. The app no longer crashes.

Comment: @sangaril Instead of editing question subject and adding SOLVED you should mark Shay's answer as accepted.

Comment: please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.
 This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. or delete the question

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the Second Activity on the manifest File:

```
<application
 .
 .
 .

 <activity android:name=".SecondScreen" />
 .
</application>
```